# Newtonsoft.Json Deserialize - Get Raw Json of Current Child Element

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I am integrating with an API that is returning me a result set. This result set has a wrapper around it. The wrapper has some other information along with a list of items. I'm successfully mapping the Json to a class using the `[JsonProperty("")]` annotations. What I'm trying to do is have a property on my class for each of the child elements to hold the raw json of that item. I can't seem to get it to work. It always returns null.

```
public class Wrapper
{
    [JsonProperty("updated")]
    public DateTimeOffset Updated { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<ChildItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ChildItem 
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string ItemId { get; set; }

    ... a bunch of other properties

    [JsonProperty("What do i put here?")]
    public string RawJson { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried swapping the property type from `string` to `JRaw`, but still haven't had any luck. I'm not looking for the entire Json response string - just the raw Json of this current item.

Comment: You want the raw JSON of the complete child object? Try putting `[JsonProperty("data")] public List<JRaw> RawItems { get; set; }` in the Wrapper class. You can later combine both via `wrapper.Items.Zip(wrapper.RawItems, (item, raw) => { … })`.

Comment: @ckuri I can't because I'm already using the json property "data" to map to my ```Wrapper.Items``` property. However, if I instead map "data" to the RawItems property like you said, I can loop thru those results and use ```DeserializeObject<ChildItem>(rawjson) ``` to build my ```Wrapper.Items``` property. That's a potential solution.

Comment: You are right, I wasn’t aware that NewtonSoft doesn‘t allow you to map the same JSON property to multiple model properties.